# Custom Error Logging in Laravel - Using different files for different error types

Tags: php, laravel, monolog

I am using laravel 4 for my project. I would like to log different kind of error to different files. For example, I am using PayPal to accept payments. Any error during payment processing, I will like to log to a different file (other than generic daily log file I am using). Is it doable ? I've tried a lot to figure it out. Everyone talks about creating your own error handler, but how do I specify that error handler to use a different log file ?

Comment: everything is in documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/errors

Comment: replace "everything" with "something". The documentation is far from complete.

Answer (score 1):

Here http://laravel.io/forum/02-09-2014-laraverl-custom-logs thats how you can create a new Logger.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. So should I create a customer error handler in Global.php and put this code inside that? I am still little confused about overall flow.

Comment: that would be on way, the otehr way you can create a custom logger class(facade) and use that for your logging in the custom error handler or where ever you want, [here])http://laravel.com/docs/errors#handling-errors) you can read more about custom error handler. 
I would go the way with a Custom Facade logger, this way you can use it everywhere and stay in laravel clean code :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep Daily Logs in seperated files / folder you can doing it using RotatingFileHandler.

```php
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler;

$log = new Logger('name');
$log->pushHandler(new RotatingFileHandler(storage_path().'/logs/folder_name/custom_log.log',2, Logger::INFO)); 

$log->info("This is a log");
```

In this example it creates a file in app/storage/logs/folder_name , and keep daily files for 2 days.